# IEEE and AIP bibliography styles in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, ieee-style

How do I use IEEE and AIP bibliography styles in biblatex? Is there a resource somewhere that has `bbx` and `cbx` style files?

For AIP, I have seen REVTeX, but it only uses the basic BibTeX `bst`, not the BibLaTeX `bbx` and `cbx`. Also, I do not know how to use just the bibliography style without having to use the REVTeX document class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have just uploaded a first version of [`biblatex-ieee`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ieee) to [CTAN](http://ctan.org/). This should implement most of the style of the BibTeX part of the [`IEEEtran`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) bundle. Obviously some testing is needed, but this should enable you to use something very close to the IEEE style using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

---

There is now also a [`biblatex-phys`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-phys) package on CTAN. At present, this covers the styles which REVTeX provides: the AIP and APS approaches.

Comment: I've seen :) PRL, Appl. Phys. Lett., Phys. Rev., Opt. Lett. all seem to have almost the same style. And if you add titles to them, you cover at least non-letter OSA journals (Optics Express, Applied Optics, JOSA). I could send a bunch of papers for examples if needed and test the style on my thesis. I've actually already tried to get the result with your existing styles, but it's tough for a biblatex newbie. BTW, a personal request: please see how online resources are referenced. In particular one doesn't always need URLs for papers and books, but does need them for web-sites.

Comment: "something very close": what would be the potential differences with the official IEEE style (i.e., what should we look out for)?

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis I've got as close as I can to the `ieeetran` documentation, but even then the _only_ official version is what _they do in their publications_. (Ultimately that might be hand-adjusted: in my own area one sees different formatting for 'unusual' references depending presumably on who actually typeset them.)

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on this point, @JosephWright. Indeed, without a precise specification it can be difficult to anticipate differences.