# How to use biblatex with IEEE bibtex style?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, ieeetran, ieee-style

```
http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEfull.bib
```

defines a bibliography style.  How to use that if I want to use biblatex to format my bibliography?

Comment: Almost duplicate of: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10727/ieee-and-aip-bibliography-styles-in-biblatex

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`biblatex` is not compatible with traditional `bibtex` styles. The IEEE style uses so-called .bst files which `biblatex` can't use. But there is a new [`bibla­tex-ieee` style](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ieee?lang=en) for `biblatex`, which probably is much more powerful.

You can call it with

`\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}`