# natbib, IEEEtran and alphanumeric citation: is there an IEEEtranSAN style available?

Tags: biblatex, natbib, ieeetran, bibunits

The `natbib` package provides three versions of the standard BibTeX bibliography styles compatible with author-year citations (`\citet`, `\citeauthor`, `\citeyear`):

- `plainnat`
- `abbrvnat`
- `unsrtnat`

The [`IEEEtran`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) package provides five different style files:

- `IEEEtran`: the standard IEEEtran BibTeX style file. For use with IEEE work.
- `IEEEtranS`: a version of IEEEtran.bst that sorts the entries.

Not for normal IEEE use:

- `IEEEtranSA`: like `IEEEtranS`, but with alphanumeric citation tags like `alpha`.
- `IEEEtranN`: like `IEEEtran`, but based on `plainnat` and is compatible with `natbib`.
- `IEEEtranSN`: sorting version of `IEEEtranN`.

Although `IEEEtranN` and `IEEEtranSN` are not recommended for normal IEEE use, `natbib` can be loaded with the [option](http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php) `numbers`, which complies with the guidelines.

I'm writing a document with several chapters and I'm using `bibunits` to generate partial references lists in some of the chapters. The references get numbered separately in the partial lists and in the global bibliography, thus each `bibitem` has two different numbers along the document, which is quite inconsistent.

It is not for normal IEEE use, so I may just use the `authoryear` option. However, many references where published in the same year, and I think that having a unique key to distinguish may help. Unfortunately, `IEEEtranSA` (with alphanumeric citation tags like `alpha`) is not compatible with `natbib`.

Do you know any style like `IEEEtran<S>AN`, which stands for alphanumeric citation tags like `alpha` and compatible with `natbib`? I'm about to start analysing the differences between `IEEEtran` and `IEEEtranN` on one side, `IEEEtranS` and `IEEEtranSA` on the other, and finally `IEEEtranS` and `IEEEtranSN`. But I'd like to know if there is any previous work which I have not found.

Comment: Is `biblatex` an option? You can use it in `natbib` compatibility mode, drop `bibunits` etc.

Comment: I don't know which are the main differences between using `natbib`+`bibunits` or just `[natbib]{biblatex}`. Does it provide `\citet`, `\citeauthor`, `\citeyear` + compatibility with `IEEEtranSA` style + the ability to define custom references blocks? Shall I maintain most of the sources, or the commands would vary?

Comment: Got it! [biblatex-ieee-alphabetic](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ieee/biblatex-ieee-alphabetic.pdf). I'm going to take a deeper look at `biblatex`...

Comment: I'm not sure about compatibility with IEEEtranSA. I'm also not sure what you mean by 'custom references blocks'. Definitely it provides `\citet` with the `natbib` mode. It provides `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear` regardless. In general, it is more flexible and much easier to customise than `bibtex`. So if you are having a problem getting `bibtex` to do what you want and `biblatex` is an option, it is definitely worth considering. It does make an awful lot of things easier. For example, there is no need for a special package for multiple bibliographies. `biblatex` has options itself.

Comment: By 'custom references blocks' I meant user-defined `bibunits`, not only references list automatically generated in each chapter/section. I've been reading about it [[1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-for-idiots)] [[2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26516/how-to-use-biber/34136)] and I think I'm going to change to `biblatex`. Thanks again for your help. I'll edit the question when I get the configuration I want.

Comment: Yes. You can do that. They don't have to match the chapter/section divisions. There are ways to match them if you want which can be automatic, but if you don't want them to match, they don't need to.

Comment: Would you consider your question answered by the edit you made to the question? If so, I would urge you to post that part as a separate answer instead - or (the more courteous option) ask the person that had suggested this solution to post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no such a style as `IEEEtranSAN` which is compatible with `natbib`. However, following the recommendation and explanations by @cfr, I've changed to [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and `biblatex-ieee`. The minimum changes are:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=ieee-alphabetic,natbib=true]{biblatex} %added
\addbibresource{IEEEfull.bib} %added
\addbibresource{IEEEexample.bib} %added

\begin{document}

\noindent
\citet{IEEEexample:article_typical} \\
\citet[chap. 2]{IEEEexample:article_typical} \\
\citep{IEEEexample:article_typical} \\
\citep[chap. 2]{IEEEexample:article_typical} \\
\citep[see][]{IEEEexample:article_typical} \\
\citep[see][chap. 2]{IEEEexample:article_typical} \\
\citet*{IEEEexample:article_typical} \\
\citep*{IEEEexample:article_typical} \\
\citeauthor{IEEEexample:article_typical} \\
\citeauthor*{IEEEexample:article_typical} \\
\citeyear{IEEEexample:article_typical} \\
\citeyearpar{IEEEexample:article_typical} \\
\cite{IEEEexample:article_typical}
\nocite{IEEEexample:shellCTANpage}

%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranSN}
%\bibliography{IEEEfull,IEEEexample}
\printbibliography %added

\end{document}
```

I get the expected results with any of the citation commands, alphanumeric keys are shown instead of numbers and the style is correct.

---

Apart from those links in the comments, I [think](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib) this Q&A is worth checking when considering to change from [`natbib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) and [`bibtex`](http://www.bibtex.org/) to [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and, probably, [`biber`](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 6):

[This shorter solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100116/164050) worked for me as I wanted to stick with IEEE numeric style but use `natbib` citation commands using:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,natbib=true]{biblatex} 
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\footnotesize} % for IEEE bibfont size
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
...
\printbibliography
```

I tried `backend` with `biber` and `bibtex` as well as `natbib` with `true` and `false`. Have fun!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Thank you for your help.