# How to cite author in IEEE format?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, ieeetran

I have to cite authors in a article using the IEEEtran bibliography format. I could use `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` and `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` to achieve that, but that would deviate from the IEEE format.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201582/natbib-ieeetran-and-alphanumeric-citation-is-there-an-ieeetransan-style-availa) question I did some days ago:

> The `natbib` package provides three versions of the standard BibTeX bibliography styles compatible with author-year citations (`\citet`, `\citeauthor`, `\citeyear`):
>
> - plainnat
> - abbrvnat
> - unsrtnat
>
> The [`IEEEtran`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) package provides five different style files:
>
> - `IEEEtran`: the standard `IEEEtran` BibTeX style file. For use with IEEE work.
> - `IEEEtranS`: a version of `IEEEtran` that sorts the entries. Not for normal IEEE use:
> - `IEEEtranSA`: like `IEEEtranS`, but with alphanumeric citation tags like alpha.
> - `IEEEtranN`: like `IEEEtran`, but based on plainnat and is compatible with natbib.
> - `IEEEtranSN`: sorting version of `IEEEtranN`.
>
> Although `IEEEtranN` and `IEEEtranSN` are not recommended for normal IEEE use, natbib can be loaded with the option numbers, which complies with the guidelines.

You may just install the `IEEEtran` package and change the style:

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
```