# IEEE Journal abbreviations with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, ieeetran

I have a bibliography file obeying BibTeX rules, which I know can be compiled always with `biblatex`. [This Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100113/how-to-use-biblatex-with-ieee-bibtex-style) already clarifies how to use `biblatex` to produce references in IEEE style.

Now the problem is that I want abbreviated journal titles generated with `biblatex` while the source is a normal `.bib` file with no abbreviations used in `journal` field (this field, in fact has two possibilities, see below).

If it were `BibTeX`, I could have used the usual `IEEEabrv.bib` that is available from [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex) to decode the abbreviations, for e.g.:

```
IEEE_J_IT = {IEEE Trans. Inf. Th.}
```

May I know how to get the same abbreviated journal titles with `biblatex`??

By the grace of JabRef, I also have the luxury of having two kinds of source `.bib` files:

1. A `.bib` source with journal field carrying short codes such as `IEEE_J_IT` -or-
2. A `.bib` source with journal field carrying *full* titles mentioned such as `IEEE Transactions on Information Theory`

All that I need is to generate the output, something like "IEEE Trans. Inf. Th.", using `biblatex`+`biber`.

Comment: Did you try using `IEEEabrv.bib`? It seems to work for me here with Biber: I can post a short demo if that is helpful.

Comment: @Joseph Wright Thank you. It would be great if you can provide the demo. Maybe you can post it as an answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Biber/`biblatex` combination should still be able to load the 'abbreviations' database:

```
% Provide some test content
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bao2015,
  author  = {Bao, Z. and Pan, G. and Zhou, W.},
  doi     = {10.1109/TIT.2015.2421894},
  issue   = {6},
  journal = IEEE_J_IT,
  pages   = {3413-3426},
  title   = {Asymptotic Mutual Information Statistics of
    {MIMO} Channels and {CLT} of Sample Covariance Matrices},
  volume  = {61},
  year    = {2015},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{IEEEabrv.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Compiling with an up-to-date Biber/`biblatex`, this comes out as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
 I some how believed that `biblatex` must have something very different :)