# Getting superscript citations in RSC Chem bibliography format

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib, biber

The RSC package is supposed to format the text so that citations appear in [] in super script however this is not happening in my text, they are in [] but inline with the text. My bibliography is also not abbreviating journal names.. 
Have googled around and tried the solution adding [super] in the preamble which is now

```
\usepackage[style=chem-rsc,backend=biber,super]{biblatex}
```

Is there anything to do with the backend or needing to use natbib which I don't fully understand?

If not is there a way to manual change all the citations in the text to subscript?

Any help at all would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The `chem-rsc.cbx` file says `autocite=superscript`. So try with `\autocite` instead of `\cite`. Never head of a `super` option.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! Do the journal abbreviations have to be adjusted manually, or is there a way of making the happen automatically

Comment: There have been quite some questions about journal abbreviations, amongst them [Is there a tool for generating journal names' abbreviations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48799/35864), [Show journal abbreviation in reference list with biblatex/biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76241/35864), [Overriding fields in a BibTeX file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107838/35864), [How to abbreviate journal name in citation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33441/35864), [IEEE Journal abbreviations with biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/248132/35864)

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of a `super` option. But if you dig into the  `chem-rsc.cbx` code, you'll find these lines:

```
\RequireCitationStyle{numeric-comp}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions
  {
    autocite  = superscript,
    autopunct = true       ,
    sorting   = none
  }
```

So using `\autocite` instead of `\cite` should do the trick.

Comment: Indeed: the semantics of `\cite` with `biblatex` are quite clear: it's an inline citation. So either `\supercite` or `\autocite` (if set up as `\supercite`) are correct here.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: But `\cite` might be superscript as a style (or even the whole of `[n]` might be superscript as a style).

Comment: No, that's rather my point: `\supercite` is for hard-coded superscripts, `\cite` is for inline citations, `\autocite` is a 'might do different things' command which can have semantics depending on the style.

Comment: Then  a simple `\let\cite=\autocite` might do what I mean? Just to save some typing…